# Definition of a "n-"simplex

Tags: simplex, simplicial-complex

I have a simple question about the definition of a simplex. In this paper by  [Jonathan Huang](http://jonathan-huang.org/research/old/sperner.pdf) he notes that every point on the simplex can be expresed as a linear combination
$$x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \alpha_i p_i$$
with $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \alpha_i \leq 1$ and $\alpha_i\geq 0$. However,  on [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf) (page 7) or on Wikipedia, for example, it is defined with $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \alpha_i =1$.

What's the most accepted definition?

Comment: @CaptainLama If we suppose $n=2$ and $p_0=(0,0)$, $p_1=(1,0)$ and $p_2=(0,1)$; I think they are the same thing.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was saying nonsense, of course the $n$-simplex *should* be the full simplex. On the other hand, the first definition is weird if one of the $p_i$ is not zero.